# html5 fluid video solution

Tags: css, html, video

I am trying to add a fluid video 
from what I have read here

https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

I am defining

```
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
height: 0;
> iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
}
```

and the on my html

```
<div class="video-container" style="padding-top:25px; width:720px">
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/xxxx?
videoFoam=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed"    

allowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen=""   
oallowfullscreen="" msallowfullscreen="" width="720"></iframe>
```

The video width is changing according the video-container width but it display a black paddings on top and on button. How can I remove those black paddings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing this in your HTML:

```
style="padding-top:25px; width:720px"
```

I'm using the same solution on my page and it works just fine.